# Connecting to MSSQL with a certificate, visual studio "new query" window gives error "The target principal name is incorrect."

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, active-directory, certificate

This is not the SSPI error that this error usually indicates

- Using sql authentication, not integrated authentication
- I am able to connect to the server just fine.
- "Test connection" reports success
- The Tables/Views/StoredProc etc trees all populate just fine
- "Show table data" works fine

But opening the "new query" window fails (prior to trying to type anything) with

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
>   error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: -2146893022)

I note that when the query window appears, the drop down list that normally contains the list of schemas (master,model, msdb) is not populated, but that might not be truly related (it could be that that list just loads after whatever point the error happened at)

Trying to run a query in the window after closing the error also fails.

This is confusing, since the "show data" link works. (perhaps because no schema is selected)

**Edit** : After further experimentation, it seems that the issue is related to certificates. As part of the information that was given to me by my DBA to connect to the database, he said to make sure that "Encrypt" was set to true, and "TrustServerCertificate" was also set to true.

I set those settings in the UI as I was creating the connection, and the connection string generated by VS reflects those settings :

```
Data Source=***********;Initial Catalog=***********;Persist Security Info=True;
User Id=***********;Password=***********;
Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

After the error message appears, a connection dialog pops up. Its slightly different than the connection dialog that is used to create the connection initially. In the advanced tab of that dialog, there is an "additional settings" textbox. If I add "TrustServerCertificate=True" to that textbox, then everything works.

But I have to let it fail, and then set that setting every time the connection is opened. Why is it not honoring the setting that was set in the initial connection dialog, and is part of the connection string produced by Visual Studio?

Comment: What happens if you add Persist Security Info=True to your connection string?

Comment: @SteveKennedy that is already in the connection string (line 2 above)